# No space left on device even after increasing the volume and partition size on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance with 2 EBS volumes. On the root volume, I increased the volume size.

First I modified the [volume size on console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/console-modify.html). Then followed this instruction to [extended the partition following this instruction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html).

However, when running any command, I get No space left on device.

```
echo "Hello" > hello.txt
-bash: hello.txt: No space left on device
```

The df -h correctly shows, the total space correctly.

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           395M  596K  394M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1       30G   19G  9.6G  67% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvdg        10G  6.2G  3.9G  62% /data2
tmpfs           395M     0  395M   0% /run/user/1001


$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  30G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0  30G  0 part /
xvdg    202:96   0  31G  0 disk /data2
```

The bottom of the [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html) said,

> If the increased available space on your volume remains invisible to
>   the system, try re-initializing the volume as described in
>   Initializing Amazon EBS Volumes.

So I followed [the instruction to reinitialize the volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-initialize.html).

I used dd to reinitialize.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/xvda of=/dev/null bs=1M

30720+0 records in
30720+0 records out
32212254720 bytes (32 GB, 30 GiB) copied, 504.621 s, 63.8 MB/s
```

However, I still get "No space left on device" error. I have done multipe reboot of the instance, I still see the same error.

Update 1: I have a large number of small files 4-10KB. So, I am running out of inodes. Please let me know how to increase the inodes (on ext4 partition)? Thanks.

```
df -i
Filesystem      Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            497270     371  496899    1% /dev
tmpfs           504717     539  504178    1% /run
/dev/xvda1     1966080 1966080       0  100% /
tmpfs           504717       1  504716    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           504717       4  504713    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           504717      18  504699    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvdg      5242880   39994 5202886    1% /data2
tmpfs           504717      10  504707    1% /run/user/1001
```

Please let me know how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to reinitialise the volumes if you are using the new generations EC2 instance type like M4, M5, T2 and T3.

You have to also expand your volume on EC2 instance:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html

As I can see your Inode is full, try this command to find the directory:

```
for i in /*; do echo $i; find $i |wc -l; done
```

Then, after finding the directory, do:

```
for i in /path/to/directory/*; do echo $i; find $i |wc -l; done
```

After that remove those file using:

```
rm -rf /path/to/fileorfoldername
```

As you don't want to remove the files, you will have to create a new filesystem using mke2fs and -I parameter for inode size, or keep increasing your root volume more.

Here is a similar question for it:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26598/how-can-i-increase-the-number-of-inodes-in-an-ext4-filesystem

Also, you can move your files to secondary drive.

Comment: I have done that. it doesn't work. I figured the issue is related to running out of inodes. Please let me know how to fix it. Do you think reducing the block size with the dd command would be sufficient?

Comment: @JackDaniels I have update my answer for inode issue please check and let me know.

Comment: I'm using a large number of small files. I should not delete them. I need a way to use large number of small files without running out of inodes.

Answer (score 0):

You are running out of inodes on your / (root) directory. so to debug it, you need:

> 1. Find what are the inodes pointing to or open files something like     `for i in /*; do echo $i; find $i |wc -l; done`
> 2. Now look for directories which take more time and then delete that dir